# Resample over a datetime and calculating mean

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have been facing a problem in which I have a set of data, and then, I want to calculate the mean speed over a period of 10 minutes. So supposing I have the following data:

```
            Timestamp      Category  ...      Status           Speed
0     2013-08-14 22:15:00         1  ...          1               10
1     2013-08-14 22:15:01         1  ...          1               10
2     2013-08-14 22:15:02         1  ...          0               10.1
3     2013-08-14 22:15:03         1  ...          1               10.1
4     2013-08-14 22:15:04         1  ...          1               12
5     2013-08-14 22:15:05         1  ...          0               12
6     2013-08-14 22:15:06         1  ...          1               13
7     2013-08-14 22:15:07         1  ...          0               12
8     2013-08-14 22:15:08         1  ...          1               11.2

35999 2013-08-23 23:35:00         0  ...          1               14.3
```

As far as I am concern, I could use pandas resample to easily calculate the mean over the 10 minutes, which would be something like this:

```
 df_mean = pd.DataFrame(df.resample('10Min', on='Timestamp')['speed'].mean())
```

The real problem here, is that I would like to have the mean starting from 22:15:00, however, when I open df_mean, the result I get is something like this:

```
2017-07-23 22:10:00    13.835333    
2017-07-23 22:20:00    12.182766   
2017-07-23 22:30:00    11.426791   
2017-07-23 22:40:00    11.776899    
2017-07-23 22:50:00    12.027970   
2017-07-23 23:00:00    13.651600    
2017-07-23 23:10:00    14.031400    
2017-07-23 23:20:00    12.182766    
2017-07-23 23:30:00    11.334857
```

I would actually something that starts from 22:15:00 and goes until 23:35:00, so the results that I would like to achieve, would be something like this:

```
2017-07-23 22:15:00    13.835333    
2017-07-23 22:25:00    12.182766   
2017-07-23 22:35:00    11.426791   
2017-07-23 22:45:00    11.776899    
2017-07-23 22:55:00    12.027970   
2017-07-23 23:05:00    13.651600    
2017-07-23 23:15:00    14.031400    
2017-07-23 23:25:00    12.182766    
2017-07-23 23:35:00    11.334857
```

Comment: Does the mean remain the same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the below what you are after?

```
df_mean = pd.DataFrame(df.resample('10Min', on='Timestamp', loffset='5min')['speed'].mean())
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> loffset : timedelta
>
> Adjust the resampled time labels